# Apache2 .htaccess rewrite rule for nested URLs doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have simple php application with navigation based on `domain/foo/bar` nested urls.

For instance, I have main page `index.php` with `about` nav link which should navigate to `domain/en/about`, where `en` and `about` must be transfered to url param like `index.php?url=...`.

But when I click to `about` I got to `domain/en/about`and
[404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC9qq.png) instead.

I have configured apache2 virtual domain config as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    <Directory /var/www/html/domain>
         Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/   
    ServerName domain.local
    ServerAlias www.domain.local
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And `.htaccess` file as:

```
order deny,allow
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

`mod_rewrite` for apache2 is already enabled.

Have no clue what I have missed.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <Directory /var/www/html/domain>
> :
> DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/
> ```

Your `<Directory>` section and `DocumentRoot` directive refer to different locations, so regardless of where you've put the `.htaccess` file, it's not going to work as intended.

However...

> ```
> RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
> ```

This rule is not strictly correct, since it ends up rewriting itself on a second pass by the rewrite engine. If it wasn't for the `QSA` flag, the original `url` param value (that contains the originally requested URL-path) would be lost. The above ends up rewriting a request for `/en/about` to `index.php?url=index.php&url=en/about`. Fortunately, your PHP script still reads `$_GET['url']` as `en/about`. But you can examine the full (erroneous) query string in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

(And, if you were to simply prefix the *substitution* string with a slash, ie. a URL-path, you'll get an endless rewrite-loop (500 Internal Server Error). But this could also result from adding additional rules later.)

You should prevent requests to `index.php` itself being rewritten, which you can do by adding an additional rule. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

However, this will still rewrite your static assets (assuming you are linking to internal images, CSS and JS files?). So, you would normally need to prevent this with an additional *condition* that prevents the rule from being processed if the request already maps to a static file.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

The *CondPattern* `-f` checks if the *TestString* maps to a file. The `!` prefix negates this. So the condition is only successful when the request does *not* map to a file.

Comment: Oh snap! You're right!
My <Directory> section and DocumentRoot directive refer to different locations, and that was the reason!

Thank you man!

Answer (score 0):

You need parenthesis around what you want to capture. Back-references indices start with '1':

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Tried this rule as well, but it didn't work, had the same results

Comment: This works perfectly in my test environment: *Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)* Does a simpler version `RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]` work for you? Do you have any other RewriteRules/RewriteConds?

Comment: This is really no different than the example posted in the question. Backreferences start at 0, not 1. `$0` refers to the entire match (which in this case is the same thing).